Как отправить видео с сайта на телеграм бота JavaScript
Я хочу что бы при запуске HTML кода либо страницу сайта, при нажатии на кнопку stop в сайте это видео отправлялось в бота который отправить это видео пользователю, то есть нужно брать видео с веб камеры телефона и отправлять в телеграм бота который будет отправлять уже мне.
Вот телеграм бота что бы бот отправлял сообщение при запуске, и затем отправлял видео
import telebot

TOKEN = 'токен'

bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Привет! Я ваш новый бот.")

# Запуск бота
bot.polling()

Вот HTML JS
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Js + Python</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="startRecording()">Start Recording</button>
  <button onclick="stopRecording()">Stop Recording</button>
  <video autoplay></video>

  <script>
    let mediaRecorder;
    const recordedChunks = [];

    navigator.mediaDevices
      .getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true })
      .then((localMediaStream) => {
        const video = document.querySelector("video");
        video.srcObject = localMediaStream;
        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(localMediaStream);

        mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(event) {
          if (event.data.size > 0) {
            recordedChunks.push(event.data);
          }
        };
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Rejected!", error);
      });

    function startRecording() {
      recordedChunks.length = 0;
      mediaRecorder.start();
    }

    function stopRecording() {
      mediaRecorder.stop();
      const blob = new Blob(recordedChunks, { type: 'video/webm' });
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('video', blob, 'video.webm');

      fetch('https://api.telegram.org/bot token/sendVideo?chat_id=id', { 
        method: 'POST', 
        body: formData 
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => console.log(data))
      .catch(error => console.error('Error sending video:', error)); 
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>```

